# Isaac blessing Jacob twice

Tags: genesis, jacob, isaac

In Genesis 27:23 (NASB)

> And he did not recognize him, because his hands were hairy like his brother Esau’s hands; so **he blessed him**.

In Genesis 27:25 (NASB)

> So he said, “Bring it to me, and I will eat of my son’s game, **that I may bless you**.”

What's the difference between the two blessings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual blessing pronounced by Isaac is recorded in Gen 27:27-29.  It is referenced as a single past event in V33, 25, 36, 37.

The solution here is as per some of the standard commentaries:

The Cambridge Commentary simply says:

> 23. blessed] Anticipating Genesis 27:26-29.

Keil and Delitzsch Biblical Commentary on the Old Testament arrives at a similar conclusion

> he did not recognise him; and "so he blessed him." In this remark
> (Genesis 27:23) the writer gives the result of Jacob's attempt; so
> that the blessing is merely mentioned proleptically here, and refers
> to the formal blessing described afterwards, and not to the first
> greeting and salutation.

Gill is less decisive:

> so he blessed him; or intended and determined within himself to bless
> him, for the blessing was not given till afterwards; unless this is to
> be understood of a common blessing, congratulating him on the quick
> dispatch he made, and the great success he met with; and after this
> gave him the patriarchal blessing, which as yet he had not, being not
> thoroughly satisfied of him, as appears by what follows.